# Order the elements of an array (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this code that I use to download nearby places (I'm working with Google place API).

```
if let response = response {
    self.response = response
    if response.status == "OK" {
        if let placesDownloaded = response.places {
            var number = numberPlaces / (categories?.count)!
            number = number == 0 ? 1 : number

            let firstPlace = placesDownloaded.prefix(1)

            var isRestaurant = false
            var isGym = false
            var isSpa = false
            var isBar = false
            var isNight_Club = false
            var isMuseum = false
            var isMovie_Theater = false

            for place in firstPlace {
                for type in place.types! {
                    if (type.lowercased() == "restaurant") {
                        isRestaurant = true
                    }
                    else if (type.lowercased() == "gym") {
                        isGym = true
                    }
                    else if (type.lowercased() == "spa") {
                        isSpa = true
                    }
                    else if (type.lowercased() == "bar") {
                        isBar = true
                    }
                    else if (type.lowercased() == "night_club") {
                        isNight_Club = true
                    }
                    else if (type.lowercased() == "museum") {
                        isMuseum = true
                    }
                    else if (type.lowercased() == "movie_theater") {
                        isMovie_Theater = true
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isRestaurant) && numberPlaces <= 4 {
                number = 1
            }
            else if(isGym) && numberPlaces > 1 {
                number = 1
            }
            else if(isSpa) && numberPlaces <= 6 {
                number = 1
            }
            else if(isNight_Club) && numberPlaces <= 3 {
                number = 1
            }
            else if(isMuseum) && numberPlaces <= 2 {
                number = 1
            }
            else if(isMovie_Theater) && numberPlaces <= 7 {
                number = 1
            }
            else if(isBar) && numberPlaces <= 2 {
                number = 1
            }

            places.append(contentsOf: placesDownloaded.prefix(number))
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to create an `if` statement to order the elements of the array `categories`. For example, something like this:

```
else if(isBar) && (isMuseum)  {
    // museum becomes the element [0] of `categories` and bar becomes the element [1]
}
```

But I really don't know how to do this. Can someone help me with an example?

Comment: It's not clear from your code or your question where you are going with this. Could you add a bit more information about what kind of data structure you are aiming to end up with?

Comment: is a lot of code, but what i want to know is only how can i order the position of the elements inside an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.sorted()` to get an ordered array:

```
let sortedCategories = categories.sorted()
```

You can pass a function to `sorted()` as well if you don't want it just sorted alphabetically but by a sorting function that you define yourself. Here for instance I am getting an array sorted by the length of each string, from shortest to longest:

```
let sortedCategoriesByLength = categories.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    return first.count < second.count
}
```